# ESP8266 Getting Unstable with the following circuit

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

When the resistors in this circuit are removed, the NodeMCU is working absolutley fine, however when these are put, ESP gets unstable and the relays are flickering. Also unable to flash with these resistors in place.

These are pull down resistors for external digitalRead as input. I need help to understand the issue better.

[image]

Comment: what happens when you remove all those jumpers? are you sure the resistors are 10k?

Comment: Does adding the resistors change the supply voltage? That would be a clue.

Comment: Which ESP8266 are you using? Your power supply outputs 5V, but you have it going into a 3.3V labeled terminal, are you sure that your ESP8266 can be powered by 5V?

Comment: Perhaps a wiring error, incorrect components, or software fault. Please provide a photo of your setup and program listing.

Comment: Its Nodemcu, works on 5VDC, i am running tasmota.one of my observation is that when r3 and r5 are in place we are unable to flash Nodemcu. This pretty much means its a electrical circuit issue i guess.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Its a printed circuit board as per the schematic shared, resistors are 10K double checked. Node MCU is running Tasmota. Let me try to share the photo of the board with component.

Comment: Are inputs D1 - D4 (mis)configured to use the internal pull-up resistors?  Using a DC voltmeter, measure the voltage across R1, R2, R3, and R5.  In the code, ensure you are using 'INPUT' and not 'INPUT_PULLUP' when configuring the pin mode for inputs D1 - D4.

Comment: @JimFischer Jim, i am using Tasmota firmware. Any idea how to verify if it is INPUT and not INPUT_PULLUP

Comment: I think i found the issue, VCC from HLK-PM01 is connected to PIN 1 of Node MCU which is expecting 3.3V and HLK-PM01 powers it with 5V. VCC from HLK should be connected to pin 30 (VIN) of node mcu. Thats very stupid of me... Thanks for the help guys, i will try to fix this up and retest again.

Comment: @Suresh, "Any idea how to verify if it is INPUT and not INPUT_PULLUP". Using a DC voltmeter, measure the voltage drop across R1, R2, R3, and R5 with your jumpers removed.  If the internal pull-up resistors are enabled (and your jumpers are removed) you'll measure a non-zero voltage drop across the resistors; otherwise, the voltage drop across the resistors should be approximately zero volts.  If the internal pull-up resistors have a value between 30k - 100k, the measured voltage drop across your resistors should be between 0.3 V to 0.825 V if the pull-ups are enabled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster found the source of a problem and it does not seem to be of any value for other users of this site

Answer (score 0):

VCC from HLK-PM01 is connected to PIN 1 of Node MCU which is expecting 3.3V and HLK-PM01 powers it with 5V. VCC from HLK should be connected to pin 30 (VIN) of node mcu. Thats very stupid of me... Thanks for the help guys, i will try to fix this up and retest again.